# Results that hold on smooth manifolds, but not on smooth manifolds with boundary?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

The only one I can think of is that the product of two smooth manifolds is a smooth manifold. This isn’t the case for smooth manifolds with boundary. Are there other results like this?

Comment: Which results are true for *both*?

Comment: @Randall Perhaps I’m misunderstanding what you’re getting at, but the existence of riemannian metric holds for both, the lie derivative is the lie bracket holds for both, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll share some examples that come to mind.

**Rank theorem, case of immersions**

> Suppose $M$ and $N$ are manifolds (without boundary) and $F : M \to N$ is a smooth immersion. For each $p \in M$, there exist a smooth chart $(U, \phi)$ for $M$ centred at $p$ and a smooth chart $(V, \psi)$ for $N$ centred at $F(p)$ such that $F(U) \subset V$, in which F has a coordinate representation of the form $$ \psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1} (x^1, \dots, x^m) = (x^1, \dots, x^m , 0, \dots , 0).$$

Now let's see what can happen if $N$ has a boundary.

Take $M = \{ t \in \mathbb R \}$ and $N = \{ (u_1, u_2) \in \mathbb R^n : u_2 \geq 0 \} $. Let $F: M \to N$ be the map $F : t \mapsto (u_1, u_2) = (t, t^2)$. This is a smooth immersion. However, the conclusion of the rank theorem (above) does not hold for the point $t = 0$. (It fails to hold even if we allow the local representation of $F$ in the conclusion of the rank theorem to shuffle the $0$'s around, and/or replace the $0$'s with constants.)

**Rank theorem, case of submersions**

> Suppose $M$ and $N$ are manifolds (without boundary) and $F : M \to N$ is a smooth submersion. For each $p \in M$, there exist a smooth chart $(U, \phi)$ for $M$ centred at $p$ and a smooth chart $(V, \psi)$ for $N$ centred at $F(p)$ such that $F(U) \subset V$, in which F has a coordinate representation of the form $$ \psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1} (x^1, \dots, x^m, x^{m+1}, \dots x^n) = (x^1, \dots, x^m).$$

Let's see what can go wrong if $M$ is a manifold with boundary.

Take $M = \{ (s_2, s_2) \in \mathbb R : s_2 \geq 0 \}$ and $N = \{ u \in \mathbb R \} $. Let $F: M \to N$ be the map $F : (s_1, s_2) \mapsto u = s_2 - s_1^2$. This is a smooth submersion. But the conclusion of the rank theorem does not hold for the point $(s_1, s_2) = (0, 0)$. (It fails to hold even if we allow the local representation of $F$ in the conclusion of the rank theorem to permute some coordinates).

**Global flows**

> Suppose $V$ is a smooth vector field on a compact manifold $M$ (without boundary). Then every maximal integral curve of $V$ is defined for $t \in \mathbb R$.

Let's see what can happen if $M$ has a boundary. Suppose $M = \{ x \in \mathbb R : x \in [-1, 1] \} $ and consider the vector field $V = \frac \partial {\partial x}$. This has a integral curve $\gamma(t) = t$, but this integral curve is only defined for $t \in [-1, 1]$. It's not defined for $t \in \mathbb R$.

**Positively oriented atlases**

> Let $M$ be a manifold (without boundary) that is orientable. Then there exists an atlas for $M$ consisting entirely of positively oriented charts.

Let's see what can happen if $M$ has a boundary. Suppose $M = \{ u \in \mathbb R : u \in [-1, 1] \} $, and pick the orientation such that $(\frac \partial {\partial u})$ is a positively oriented at each point. The boundary chart $\phi : (-1, 1] \subset M$ defined by $\phi : u \mapsto x^1 = (1 - u)$ is negatively oriented. We can't "flip" this chart to make it positively oriented, because of our conventions that the final local coordinate for a boundary chart must be positive.

---

**Edit:** It might be helpful if I also list some important theorems that **do** hold for manifolds with boundary in the same way that they hold for manifolds without boundary.

- A manifold (with or without boundary) is locally path connected. (Hence its connected components are the same as its path components, and each connected component is an open subset.)
- Given an open cover for a manifold (with or without boundary), there exists a smooth partition of unity subordinate to this open cover. (This allows us to do many useful things. For example, this enables us to construct smooth extensions of functions that are only defined on a closed subset. This also enables to us to come up with a reasonable definition of the integral of differential forms on the manifold. All these constructions work fine for manifolds with boundary just as they do for manifolds without boundary.)

Comment: Thank you! Is there some "moral" reason for these statements to fail? More precisely, given a result that holds on a smooth manifold, is there a way to make an educated guess about whether or not it should hold on smooth manifolds with boundary?

Comment: @Chris In the four examples I've given, it's visually intuitive that the conclusions of the theorems should fail, right? A simple picture in each example is enough to convince me.

Comment: I agree that in your counter examples this is visually intuitive. I guess I was more so wondering if there some obvious topological aspect of manifolds with boundary that could lead to this conclusion that I'm missing. I guess just being locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{H}^n$ in boundary charts is enough though.

Comment: For the rank theorem counterexamples, the reason why the conclusion of the theorem fails to hold for manifolds with boundary is that, _by definition_, the boundary must appear as a flat hyperplane in a boundary chart. If the definition of boundary charts allowed for boundary charts where the boundary appears as a curved hypersurface, then you can easily get the conclusion of the theorem to hold for my so-called counterexamples. But whoever wrote the definition of boundary charts decided not to write the definition that way...

Comment: For the global flow counterexample, clearly the reason why you can't extend the flow for an infinite period of time is that you eventually hit the boundary and can't continue.

Comment: For the positively oriented charts counterexample, the reason we can't get the conclusion of the theorem to hold is again due to the definition of how boundary charts should look. This time, the difficulty is due to a mere technicality: The image of the boundary chart must lie in the positive half-plane; you're not allowed to have boundary charts whose image lie in the negative half-plane. It's banal, but there it is.

Comment: Let me also make a comment on the partition of unity theorem, explaining why the theorem _does_ hold for manifolds with boundary. In the proof of the theorem, the key property of manifolds that we're exploiting is that the topology for the manifold has a basis consisting entirely of _regular balls_ (where a regular ball is some ball that lies entirely in a single chart, and whose closure lies inside some large ball that also lies entirely within that same chart). For manifolds with boundary, a similar property holds, provided that we include _regular half-balls_ in our basis.

Comment: It seems your third counter example for a positively oriented atlas does not hold when $\dim M>1$, according to proposition 15.6 in Lee's smooth manifolds, unless I am missing some subtle distinction between positively oriented charts, and a consistently oriented atlas.

Comment: @Chris That's right! I deliberately made it so that $dim M = 1$ in my counterexample

Comment: Oh i see, it doesn't hold for all manifolds with boundary, duh. my bad.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clear. On a manifold with boundary of dimension $2$, if you have a negatively oriented chart, then you can flip the _non-boundary_ coordinate to turn it into a positively oriented chart.